# storing user uid instead of refresh token to keep user signed in?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase authentication in my project and my question is, what is the problem  of storing just **user uid** instead of **refresh token** that expires in short time so i can keep user logged in.

I am using `signInWithEmailAndPassword` ,method to sign in users and get user object from `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged`

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChange(authUser=> setUser(authUser))
```

Now i can use `authUser.user.uid` and store it in localStorage.

My question is not related to **firebase** or any other library, but i am asking about a general behavior, what is the problem in storing something that don't expire??

My question is, **how bad is doing this??**

Comment: Basically, if anyone who has userid will get access to your application in future. It is never expiring and limits to add more secured functionality. You can issue a token with longer expiration date instead.

Comment: Firebase already persists the authentication state in local storage. There is no need for you to do the same. If you reload the page, your `onAuthStateChange` should already fire, unless you've explicitly disabled the built-in local storage.

Comment: In addition: storing the UID is not enough to keep the user signed in. While a UID identifies a user, it is not enough to authenticate them.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen That's right, firebase persists user once authenticated, i only need to set a piece of state that set authentication to true or false depending on the existence of the user on authentication global object, thanks, it is easier now and more intuitive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use `Authentication State Persistence` like the example below:

```
firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)
  .then(function() {
    // Existing and future Auth states are now persisted in the current
    // session only. Closing the window would clear any existing state even
    // if a user forgets to sign out.
    // ...
    // New sign-in will be persisted with session persistence.
    return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
  });
```

**Learn more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence)**

Comment: thank you i actually achieved that persistence by pushing the user uid to local storage, my question us how bad is doing that, is this an odd behavior?

Comment: @CodeEagle I don't think it's a good idea to store it that way I recommend using the method provided from firebase, that behaviour can lead to some issues as the token will never expire. Another problem would be how would you log out the user?

Comment: @Thank yu, no problem about logout, just a button or nav link that remove item from localStorage

Comment: how your code keep user logged in without saving something in localStorage??

Comment: @CodeEagle using session

Comment: @CodeEagle the only downside that the user will have to login in again after closing a tab a better solution will be using a cookie, you can check how it works with firebase from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies).